# ToggleSwitch Header Color

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a ToggleSwitch control and the header text is white. The Off and On text is black.
How can i change the header text to black?
The code is below

```
     <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="Toggle" Header="Background process" Margin="0,20,0,460" 
     Checked="ToggleSwitch_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleSwitch_Unchecked" Background="Black" 
     Foreground="black" FontSize="40">        
     </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

Comment: Make sure that whatever you're doing, you're respecting the dark/light OS themes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.Header>
        <TextBlock Text="Background process" Foreground="Black" />
    </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.Header>
</toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change value of property background and foreground.

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="Toggle" Header="Background process" Margin="0,20,0,460" 
 Checked="ToggleSwitch_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleSwitch_Unchecked" Background="white" 
 Foreground="black" FontSize="40">        
 </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```